# In C: using void and int keywords while pointing to functions

Tags: c

I am trying to do a program where the function is pointed by a pointer. It goes as follows:-

This is the first program which uses "void" return type.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void CharPrint(char *ptr);
main()
{
    char *str="Hello World";
    void (*ptr1)(char *ptr);
    ptr1=CharPrint;
    if((*ptr1)(str))
        printf("Done");
    return 0;
}
void CharPrint(char *ptr)
{
    printf("%s\n",ptr);
}
```

It throws many errors. They are:-

[image]

The second program is as follows:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int CharPrint(char *ptr);
main()
{
    char *str="Hello World";
    int (*ptr1)(char *ptr);
    ptr1=CharPrint;
    if((*ptr1)(str))
        printf("Done");
    return 0;
}
int CharPrint(char *ptr)
{
    printf("%s\n",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This program runs without any hiccup.

The output is:-

[image]

My problem is that in the first output, why is it showing " Not an allowed type in function main " on line 9. The other lines are also arising doubts but this line is bugging me the most. Any help?

Comment: Well, at least the "void function may not return value" is an obvious one. Are you sure you're compiling the code you're showing us here? Also, your code isn't proper C; rather, it's a style of C that was used tentatively in the 1970s. You might want to get a modern source of knowledge.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am compiling the code that I am showing you here. However, the concept of " not returning anything " seems logical. However, the main problem is on line 9. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @kusur if in your editor line 9 is the if condition then that will give you the error.It might not be getting anything to test.

Comment: Can you mark the problematic lines? I can't count to nine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void (*ptr1)(char *ptr);
ptr1=CharPrint;
if((*ptr1)(str))
    printf("Done");
```

What is the `if` testing if the return value is `void`? Just change the last two lines to:

```
((*ptr1)(str));
```

Comment: It was really stupid of me to think that a void function would return something. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

Your first function does not return anything. Thus, you cannot test 
`if((*ptr1)(str))` .